# Failed to read initial state with useContext in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that I would like to unit test with Jest/React Testing Library. It destructures an initial state from `useContext()`. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'initialState')]

Obviously, `StateProvider` wrapping `Component` does not work with the error. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue? Here are related files.

```
// reducer.ts
export const initialState: IInitialStateContext = {
  initialState: [],
};

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

```
// StateProvider.tsx
interface StateProvierProps {
  reducer: any;
  initialState: IInitialStateContext;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface IStateContext {
  state: IInitialStateContext | unknown;
  dispatch: ({ type }: { type: string }) => void;
}

export const StateContext = createContext({} as IStateContext);

export const StateProvider = ({
  reducer,
  initialState,
  children,
}: StateProvierProps) => {
  return (
    // @ts-ignore
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

```
// Component.tsx
const Component: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
}: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [{ initialState }, dispatch] = useStateValue(); // The error occurs here
  ...
```

```
// Component.test.tsx
describe("Component", () => {
  it("should render correctly", () => {
    const prop1 = "prop1";
    const prop2 = "prop2"
    const prop3 = "prop3"
    const mockReducer = jest.fn();
    const mockContext = {
      initialState: [{
      id: "",
      }]
    }
      render(
    <StateProvider initialState={mockContext} reducer={mockReducer}>
      <Component
        prop1={mockProp1}
        prop2={mockProp2}
        prop3={mockProp3}
      />
    </StateProvider>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useReducer` hook signature:

```
function useReducer<R extends Reducer<any, any>>(
    reducer: R,
    initialState: ReducerState<R>,
    initializer?: undefined
): [ReducerState<R>, Dispatch<ReducerAction<R>>];
```

The `IStateContext` type should be a tuple type:

```
type IStateContext = [IInitialStateContext, ({ type }: { type: string }) => void];
```

Complete example:

`StateProvider.tsx`:

```
import React, { createContext, Reducer, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { IInitialStateContext } from './reducer';

interface StateProvierProps {
  reducer: Reducer<any, any>;
  initialState: IInitialStateContext;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

type IStateContext = [IInitialStateContext, ({ type }: { type: string }) => void];

export const StateContext = createContext({} as IStateContext);

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }: StateProvierProps) => {
  return <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>;
};
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

`reducer.ts`:

```
export type IInitialStateContext = {
  initialState: any[];
};
export const initialState: IInitialStateContext = {
  initialState: [],
};

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => state;

export default reducer;
```

`Component.tsx`:

```
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';

export type IProps = {
  prop1: any;
  prop2: any;
  prop3: any;
};
export const Component = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }: IProps) => {
  const [{ initialState }] = useStateValue();
  console.log(" ~ file: Component.tsx:10 ~ Component ~ initialState:", initialState)
  return null;
};
```

`Component.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from './Component';
import reducer from './reducer';
import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider';

describe('Component', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const prop1 = 'prop1';
    const prop2 = 'prop2';
    const prop3 = 'prop3';
    const mockContext = { initialState: [{ id: '' }] };
    render(
      <StateProvider initialState={mockContext} reducer={reducer}>
        <Component prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} prop3={prop3} />
      </StateProvider>
    );
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75531868/Component.test.tsx (8.661 s)
  Component
    ✓ should render correctly (30 ms)

  console.log
     ~ file: Component.tsx:10 ~ Component ~ initialState: [ { id: '' } ]

      at Component (stackoverflow/75531868/Component.tsx:10:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.142 s
```